# Are unreferenced default parameters automatically tree-shaken out by webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

> Obligatory apologies if this has been asked before, but I've been
> unable to find an answer online or in the webpack docs related to tree shaking.

How does tree-shaking work with default parameters? For context: I'm specifically concerned with how the webpack implementation of tree-shaking handles default parameters.

Given the following hypothetical application structure:

```
/
|_ dependency/
| |
| |_ dependency.js
| |_ moderatelyLargeFile.js
|
|
|_src/
  |
  |_ application.js
  |_ someSmallFile.js
```

and the following code in each file:

`dependency.js`

```
import moderatelyLargeFile from './moderatelyLargeFile.js';
import { someParsingFunction1, someParsingFunction2 } from 'somewhere-else-dependency';

export default function parseSomeFile(file = moderatelylargeFile) {
  let parsedResult = { ...someParsingFunction1(file), ...someParsingFunction2(file) };
  return parsedResult;
}
```

`application.js`

```
import parseSomeFile from './dependency/dependency.js';
import someSmallFile from './someSmallFile.js'
let result = parseSomeFile(someSmallFile);
// Do other application stuff with result
```

Would `moderatelyLargeFile.js` ever be bundled into the webpack build of `application.js`? Is webpack smart enough to know that the default parameter is never referenced because the single invocation provides that parameter? Or does the `moderatelyLargeFile.js` always get bundled regardless because it is part of the function definition?

Answer (score 1):

No – as of April 2022, dead-code elimination of unused default parameters is not currently supported in any known bundlers.

I put together [a repo with examples for the major bundlers](https://github.com/bitjson/shake-default-params), it tests how various bundlers handle tree shaking/dead-code elimination of [Libauth](https://libauth.org/)'s WebAssembly crypto implementations. (A good real-world example where some bundles could save hundreds of KBs.)

I also opened issues for the bundlers I'm familiar with:

- https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2185
- https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7961
- https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4466
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15671

I'll try to update this answer when various bundlers add support. That repo also has [a table](https://github.com/bitjson/shake-default-params#bundler-support).

Comment: Thank you very much for this high quality response! The current status on 2023-12-28: 
- Won't fix for ESBuild
- Implemented in Rollup \:D/
- automatically closed in Webpack
- Moved from parcel to terser and still opened there